# User Registration to appear in a block

Tags: users

I want the user registration to appear in a block in some other page than home, let's say a page called "Sign up." What I want to achieve is the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: you should check out the logintoboggon module

Comment: hi...thanks for reply..i tried that..but it simple redirects to the normal registration page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve according to your use case you have to render login form on node or on page, if i am not wrong.

You can add following snippet to render the login form.

The `user_block_view()` function has this line in it for the `login` delta:

```
if (!$user->uid && !(arg(0) == 'user' && !is_numeric(arg(1)))) {
```

If you're logged in, the function will return an empty array, which is probably what's happening in your case.

If that's not the reason (and even if it is) you can get around it by calling the form function directly:

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block'));
```

There doesn't appear to be any extra access checks done in the form function so it should be rendered regardless of whether you're logged in or not.

Comment: hi..m quite new at drupal..can u tell me which file do i have to edit and where can i find them...i am using a zen starter theme

Comment: but as shown in your use case there is image for login, can you briefly explain me where exactly do you want to integrate this form in your drupal site

Comment: i want to integrate it in a new page

Comment: Then you have to add this code in page.tpl.php file..but if you have understanding of panel then you can try the solution given by @Nikhil N

Comment: hi again..i have added the formblock-user register in the panel but its not showing up..even in preview...why so?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache ?

Comment: @nikhil...its works...after clearing the cache though..thanks a ton

Answer (score 11):

Well there is [Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/formblock)

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or
>   node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for
>   including forms on panels.

Download and install the module.
Navigate to `admin/structure/block` You can see Registration form as a block there.

[image]

Comment: hi..how do i enable it for user registration block

Comment: hi again..i have added the formblock-user register in the panel but its not showing up..even in preview...why so?

Comment: @kewal See my edit

Comment: To see the regn form you should be logged out.

Comment: @Nikhil..thanks a lot..i had done that but the changes were not reflecting...i cleared the cache once..now its there..thank you

Comment: @Nikhil...i want it to be displayed only on a specific page..so after i placed it in a block (second sidebar) i configured it to display on only listed pages...the path as shown in my browser is localhost/node/38 and i used this path enclosed within <> but the form is not displayed..i also have cleared the cache

Comment: I also cleared the cache but the user register block is not visible.Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty simple to handle this. I fixed this on Drupal 7 like below

1. Create block say 'User register form' in content top.
2. Put this code in its body
   `<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form')); ?>`
3. In text format select PHP code
4. In visibility settings, under roles select 'Anonymous user' or who ever who wants to see the form.

Comment: One addition: You also require Drupal core's php module in order to see the PHP text format.